# Using mono on linux (Ubuntu) c#

Tags: c#, linux, mono

I'm trying to run a c# program on using the gmcd command on linux using:

```
gmcd Main.cs
```

I get the same error 8 times;

```
Main.cs: error Cs0246: The type or namespace name 'UtilLib' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference
```

The first few lines of the code is;

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Threading;
using System.Globalization;
using UtilLib;
using UtilLib.CRC;
using UtilLib.IO;
using UtilLib.ConsoleUtility
```

I have a folder named UtilLib full of .cs files in the same directory as Main.cs and have tried the command:

```
gmcs /reference:UtilLib Main.cs
```

but that just returned the error cannot find metadate file 'UtilLib'

Comment: I think you need to provide `gmcd` with all the source files required to build the project. So something like `gmcd Main.cs Window.cs UtilLib/CRC.cs UtilLib/IO.cs` etc..

Comment: I'd recommend a build system of some sort. If you want to use Visual Studio/MonoDevelop for managing files, but be capable of building from the command line, you can use `xbuild`